# Transfer image represented as blob using JSON

Tags: javascript, java

I have an image on the client side (javascript) represented as [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob). I need to transfer it using JSON to the Java backend in a way that it will be possible to decode it back to image on the Java side. The process is straightforward, but i have problems with choosing suitable datastructures.

Comment: Not sure, can you try base64encode?

Comment: Send image to server side as `base64` and then convert `base64` to `byte[]` representation to create `Blob`